# CSS backface-visibility not showing on cardflip in a parent div

Tags: css

I am trying to make an opening book animation with CSS transitions similar to a card flip animation except with another card behind it.

When I create a single card flip it works fine in chrome. But if I put it inside a parent div in order to place another card behind it the back of the card no longer shows.

#### HTML

```
<div class="scene">
    <div class="turncard">
        <div class="turncard-front">
            <div class="turncard-outside turncard-side">
              Front!!!<br/>I don't work
            </div>
            <div class="turncard-inside turncard-side">
              Back!!!<br/>Can you see me?
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.scene {
  margin-left: 200px;
  perspective: 6000px;
}
.turncard {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.turncard-front {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.turncard-side {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.turncard-outside{
  z-index: 1;
}
.turncard-inside {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.turncard-front:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Both the working version (without a parent div) and non-working example (with the div) are shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxLa4kwu/1/

Comment: In latest FF version they have the same behavior,

Comment: Interesting. For me in firefox 33 they are both broken. The top one displays the text of both the front and back on top of eachother after flipping and the bottom one only shows the front text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick this property on `.turncard2-front`:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxLa4kwu/3/

This property tells it to preserve the 3D position of children of the turncard2-front element (e.g. inside and outside of the page) when turncard2-front is css transformed.

Be aware this doesn't work in IE11 as the property isn't supported (but you probably knew that as the first example doesn't work either in IE).

Comment: doesn't work in FF. Try testing in all Modern Browsers before answering.

Comment: @dippas Fine here :http://jsfiddle.net/bxLa4kwu/3/ I made the not unreasonable assumption that the op was capable of adding a simple -moz- prefix to my change.

Comment: I know what you mean. I knew that was a right answer, just try to assume that OP always doesn't know anything, and you have to be very explanatory in your answer. You understand my point?

Comment: It makes rather a lot of sense now you've pointed it out. 
Much appreciated.

Comment: @dippas yeah I do - I usually edit my answer for completeness after submitting (e.g. adding the point about no IE support in this particular answer).